# Python matplotlib - How to draw line chart with many series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I had a python pandas dataframe like below:

```
    test_score  param   # of Nodes
0   0.497852    relu        1
1   0.68935     relu        2
2   0.701165    relu        3
3   0.735223    identity    1
4   0.735064    identity    2
5   0.735691    identity    3
6   0.72651     logistic    1
7   0.664837    logistic    2
8   0.743445    logistic    3
9   0.705182    tanh        1
10  0.673399    tanh        2
11  0.684129    tanh        3
```

I would like to draw the line chart with x axis as "# of Nodes", y axis as "test_score", and four param values "relu, identity, logistic, tanh" as 4 series lines.

Could this chart be plotted in python matplotlib?

Comment: Did you try anything? Like `df.groupby("param").plot(x="# of nodes", y="test_score")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by grouping by `param`, then iterating through your groups and plotting:

```
g = df.groupby('param')

for p, data in g:
    plt.plot(data['# of Nodes'], data['test_score'], label=p)

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('# of Nodes')
plt.ylabel('Test Score')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have all nodes for all parameters like in your example you can `.pivot` your `DataFrame` to a more suitable format for plotting them all.

```
df.pivot(index='# of Nodes', columns='param', values='test_score').plot()
```

[image]